# How to change mysql port

Tags: mysql, wamp, ports

I'm using wampserver. And suddenly mysql wouldn't work. I checked curports from nirsoft and it has red highlight on it. What does it mean?How do I solve this so that I could use mysql again. I'm working on a project but I can't move on if the database won't work. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for changing the mysql port, just change it in my.ini. Look for this line

port=3306

you should check mysql log and windows log for detecting why MySQL is not working.

You can also try disabling the firewall